# XCUITest non-blocking press forDuration

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator, xcuitest

I'm writing some XCUITests. I have a screen where something changes on the screen while the user holds their finger on an element. I'm trying to write a test something like the below, where I check what the value is first, press and hold, while checking that the value is not the same

```
let element = app.staticTexts["selected-date"]
XCTAssert(dateElement.label == "Today", dateElement.label)

tablesQuery.staticTexts["annotation"].press(forDuration: 3)
XCTAssert(dateElement.label != "Today", dateElement.label)
```

I need the second check to happen during the hold. But `press(forDuration: )` is a blocking call that stops the runner for 3 seconds. Resulting in the check running after. Is there anyway to make a non-blocking hold, or anything like that?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't, it's all synchronous. Even with expectations that are usually used for asynchronous behaviour, it still blocks until the expectation is met or not met. A way to test is to have a "delay" introduced just when running UI tests(by providing an argument to the test runner for example that will enable it), so you can check it after you release the press. It will take some work from the developers and might not be suitable at all for your use case of course :)